# GTest for multithreaded process

Tags: multithreading, googletest

I am running GTest for my one process which will be multi threaded.

I am compiling all the code of the process in Gtest environment and then testing the code through test cases.

My problem is as below

```
TEST(TestCase1,TestCase11)
{
Point 1 //i am calling one event of the class over here...the class will be having its separate thread.
Point 2 //Now over here if i am not putting a usleep of some seconds then the event in that separate thread is not getting covered.
}
```

One thing to note over here that it is a event, which will be handled by the framework such that when Point 1 is generating the event then it will return the execution to point 2.. but will continue to process some things in the context of the thread in which the event was defined. It is not a function Call.

Can anyone help over here. How to remove that usleep because the time varies many times because of the execution time taken by the events will be different.

Comment: You'll need to synchronize manually with the processing thread before executing _Point 2_. AFAIK, GTest does not provide (how could it?) any facilities to wait for user triggered asynchronous operations.

Comment: Ok that means i need to have a way to check whether the thread is now in idle state means it has processed everything and now i can go ahead and test other things.?

Comment: I would rather check that thread has actually run and finished, otherwise you could run into a race condition if _Point 2_ is reached before it has actually started.

Comment: I tried on checking that but thats somewhat difficult, But while compiling for gtest can tweak something so that the pthreads are not getting created ? and all run on the single thread only when the functions are called through the tests?

Comment: Or i can get the thread id of the thread ?  i can check from that whether thread is stopped ? because first while testing it will be a function call which will run on the main(gtest) thread context and in that only will generate a event which will be run on the other thread context.Hence that thread will start running hence after that function call is return i need to check whether the thread is finished? Can i check that using the thread id?